# python2-requests package missing in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, python-2.7

I do not see any package named `python2-requests` in the apt search results. I do not see `pip2` either. How can I install requests module for python2 ?

Comment: The `python-requests` (not python**2**-requests) package was dropped from Ubuntu after 19.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download python-requests package for Ubuntu 19.10 to your desktop from the official Ubuntu download page for [python-requests_2.21.0-1_all.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/all/python-requests/download). Install python-requests_2.21.0-1_all.deb from the terminal with the following commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
sudo apt install ./python-requests_2.21.0-1_all.deb
```

You don't need to download any additional dependencies to install python-requests_2.21.0-1_all.deb because all of the required dependencies will be installed from the default Ubuntu 20.04 repositories, and it's not necessary to install anything with pip because it's all done with one apt command.

Comment: or just simple `sudo apt-get install python-requests` to get 2.18.4.2ubuntu0.1 python-requests
elegant and simple HTTP library for Python2, built for human beings oops that was on my 18.04 I will look on 20 04

Comment: @JohnOrion That command will not work in 20.04 because the python-requests package has been discontinued in the Ubuntu 20.04 default repositories, although all of its dependencies are still there in 20.04. Elegant and simple in this case would be if Launchpad still maintains this package, however it doesn't.

Comment: ahh .. ok .. I guess it going away was quicker than I though .. forgot I was on my 18.04 version when I checked it .. lol and my 20.04 hasn't booted yet :)

Comment: I often wonder why they had 2 versions .. now that they are removing "python" do you always have to use python3 to launch python or are they finally going to change the name so that python runs python3 not 2... lol I guess you could do that "manually" lol

Comment: @JohnOrion they will NOT be changing the name in the foreseeable future. That would cause tremendous confusion and breakage needlessly.